# Angular - Jasmine test going into a loop when detectChanges is not called in the beginning

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have the below code testing functionality of pressing a button triggering the ngSubmit handler:

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, tick, fakeAsync } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { AuthComponent } from './auth.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

describe('AuthComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthComponent>;
    let comp: AuthComponent;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let ne: HTMLElement;
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MatButtonModule,
                MatFormFieldModule,
                MatInputModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
            providers: [],
            declarations: [AuthComponent]
        }).compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthComponent);
        de = fixture.debugElement;
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        ne = de.nativeElement;
    }));
 

    it('is expected to have the button press trigger onLogin', fakeAsync(() => {

        let button = de.query(By.css('button[name=login]'));
        // let form = de.query(By.css('form'));
        fixture.detectChanges();
        spyOn(comp, 'onLogin');

        //form.triggerEventHandler('submit', null);
        button.nativeElement.click();                
        tick();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(comp.onLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();        

    }));
});
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Please Login</h1>

<form class="form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()">
    <mat-form-field class="form__field">
            <input matInput type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username"/>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field class="form__field">
            <input matInput type="text" name="pass" placeholder="Password" formControlName="pass"/>
    </mat-form-field>
    <button class="form__submit" color="primary" name="login" mat-raised-button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

below is the TS code for the component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    FormBuilder,
    FormControl,
    FormGroup,
    FormGroupDirective,
    Validators,
    ValidationErrors
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'sen-auth',
    templateUrl: './auth.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./auth.component.scss']
})

export class AuthComponent {
    readonly loginForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.loginForm = fb.group({ username: [], pass: [] })
    }
    public onLogin(): void {
        console.log('onLogin called');
        // if (this.loginForm.valid) {

        // }
    }
}
```

When the test has the first `fixture.detectChanges` call it passes. If that is removed, we go into a loop I expect is caused by form submission not being intercepted by Jasmine. Can someone explain what theis first `detectChanges` call is doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be quick, see `fixture.detectChanges` as a method to update the DOM for your test. Without, your test doesn't have a populated DOM.

> By using the ATB and fixtures we can inspect the components view through fixture.debugElement and also trigger a change detection run by calling fixture.detectChanges(). [source](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/change-detection/#_summary)

A better order would be :

```
it('is expected to have the button press trigger onLogin', () => {
   spyOn(comp, 'onLogin');
   fixture.detectChanges();

   let button = de.query(By.css('button[name=login]'));

   button.nativeElement.click();                

   fixture.detectChanges(); // Properties inside your component have probably changed. We need to update the DOM to see it.

   expect(comp.onLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();        

}));
```

Comment: That does not answer the question of why removing the first call causes  tests running in a loop.